# PropertyChangeSupport in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

In my gwt application somebody developed a module which uses java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport. Recently I have started using that module and getting **The import java.beans cannot be resolved**  error when I run. But application runs well. Why am I getting compiler error in gwt dev mode window? Any ideas?

```
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/workspace/App/src/main/java/com/abc/def/client/extract/pojos/ClientData.java'
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 3: The import java.beans cannot be resolved
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 4: The import java.beans cannot be resolved
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 11: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 14: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 14: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 17: PropertyChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 18: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 21: PropertyChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 22: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 25: PropertyChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 26: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 30: PropertyChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 31: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 36: PropertyChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type
00:17:33.079  [ERROR] Line 36: PropertyChangeSupport cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) mentioned by BobV are great new feature of GWT, however refactoring of your existing code would be required in order to use them. If your application already uses `PropertyChangeSupport`, the [gwtx](http://code.google.com/p/gwtx/) project provides GWT emulation of `java.beans.PropertyChange*` classes.

Answer (score 2):

GWT only implements a [subset of the JRE types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).  The reason that DevMode works is that it compiles your Java source against the system's JRE types for better runtime performance.  When running the production-mode compile, it uses the files in `gwt-user.jar` at `com/google/gwt/emul/java/...`.

General-purpose reflection is incompatible with dead-code stripping and many forms of monolithic optimization, so the GWT compiler doesn't implement runtime reflection.  The GWT [Generator system](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator.html) has access to the module's entire typesystem at compile-time, so you can implement enough "static" reflection to suit your needs.

If you're building a system based on "bags of state" you might want to look at the [AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) framework, which provides lightweight property reflection through a visitor pattern.